# 500 Internal Server Error: npm@latest

Tags: npm

I have a problem with npm I can't get any package. For example running :

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

gives :

```
npm ERR! code E500 npm ERR! 
500 Internal Server Error: npm@latest
```

If I try to access https://registry.npmjs.org/ I get :

```
Fastly error: unknown domain. 
Please check that this domain has been added to a service.
```

I looked into my /etc/hosts and nothing wrong there, any ideas ?

```
---------------- INFOS -----------

    NodeJS : v9.2.0
    npm    : 6.0.1
    OS     : Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
```

Comment: Make sure you don't have any redirections in your `/etc/hosts` file if you have something like this `x.x.x.x.x registry.npmjs.org` where Xs are the IP, then just remove this line

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I think this may be related to a large set of possible reasons. In my case it was related to my internet service provider which was blocking the repo website. I asked them directly.

Answer (score 10):

Below step resolve my npm registry issue. I hope same will be work for you.

1. Try to set npm registry using : `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`
2. Check result of `curl https://registry.npmjs.org/`
3. Clear the cache: `npm cache clean --force`
4. Try to run `npm install`

Answer (score 2):

From corporate network sometimes you won't be able to properly resolve registry.npmjs.org. To workaround the problem do the following.

> dig registry.npmjs.org @1.1.1.1

Take any of the ip in the output and add to /etc/hosts

> 104.16.16.35 registry.npmjs.org

You should be good to go now.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue.

> Below solution worked for me at least:

**comment out** this part in windows *hosts* file

```
# 151.101.0.162 registry.npmjs.org
```

Answer (score 1):

500 error indicates issue with the server. Yesterday I was facing this issue whenever I tried installing packages with npm. Upon searching a bit, I found [status.npmjs.org](https://status.npmjs.org/). It's a page that shows the current status of npm registry. There was an outage due to DNS misconfiguration which was mentioned on the page.I kept checking the status page, and eventually there was a status update :

> Update - This has now been resolved for most users and we will continue to monitor until it has cleared for everyone. 
>   Sep 1, 17:13 UTC

After this update, I was able to install packages without any issues.